# Fence/delimiter stored inside in a macro

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I'm wondering, say I have this definition

```
\newcommand\restrictedTo{\vert\sb}
```

to be used as `$f \restrictedTo A$`.

This works fine, but

```
$f \big \restrictedTo A$
```

fails, whereas

```
$\left. f \right \restrictedTo A$
```

work just fine.

Any suggestions for a better definition for `\restrictedTo`?

Edit: here is a full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand\restrictedTo{\vert\sb}
\begin{document}
\[
  f \big\restrictedTo A
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David has already explained, that `\big` takes an argument, what breaks the original definition after `\big`.
An alternative for redefining `\big` (and `\Big`, …) is to give `\restrictedTo` an optional argument:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand*\restrictedTo[1][]{#1\vert\sb}
\begin{document}
\[
  f \restrictedTo A,
  f \restrictedTo[\big] A,
  f \restrictedTo[\Big] A
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If you only want to have a lower position of `A`, then you would not need `\big` and the definition and usage can be simplified:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand*\restrictedTo{{{}\vert}\sb}

\begin{document}
\[
  f \vert_A,
  f \restrictedTo A,
  f \big\vert_A
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with lower subscript]

Comment: That was what I did, just hoped there was a better solution

Answer (score 7):

`\right` is a TeX primitive which expands tokens ahead of itself until it finds a non-expandable delimiter.

`\big` is a normal macro command that reads the next token as `#1`

```
\def\big#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to8.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
```

so you could go

```
\expandafter\big \restrictedTo
```

But that isn't really very convenient.

It is probably safe in practice (although could break some things) to go

```
\let\oldbig\big
\def\big{\expandafter\oldbig}
```

then your initial example would work.